# get max id from multipe rows and same ref id

Tags: php, mysql, max

i need the row with the max id where the status is 1 and newest date without an a_id (619) in the WHERE query available.

In this example i want to get only the row with id 876

```
`id`, `a_id`, `status`, `date`
(876,  619,     1,     '2020-05-08 10:02:17'),
(875,  619,     0,    '2020-05-08 09:41:30'),
(874,  619,     1,    '2020-05-08 09:29:08'),
(873,  619,     1,    '2020-05-08 09:23:30'),
(872,  619,     0,    '2020-05-08 09:20:14'),
(871,  619,     1,    '2020-05-08 09:18:09');
```

I thought some thing like this but it does not work

```
SELECT a_id,MAX(id)
FROM stats          
WHERE status = 1 
GROUP BY a_id
```

Comment: 876 has 619 as it's a_id

Comment: It doesn't work because of CURDATE() > DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 3 MONTH). What are you trying to get with it?

Comment: assuming your id is unique you can have it in 2 "steps" : select * from stats where id = (SELECT MAX(id)
FROM stats          
WHERE status = 1 AND CURDATE() > DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 3 MONTH))

Comment: Maybe the problem is your `WHERE` condition.

Comment: ```WHERE status = 1 AND `date` < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 3 MONTH```?

Comment: no if i remove CURDATE() > DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL 3 MONTH)...i just get the row with id 871...thats not the max id

Comment: Yes, of course, you cannot  get the maximum id which's `876` because of this `GROUP BY a_id`

Comment: Tuckbros...there are more rows with other a_id number...with your query i only get one row back (its the highest id thats correct)

Comment: Jesper Martinez without i only get one row back

Comment: @EdwinSwart Yes, you're right!